# Set caching policy for rewritten request

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, cache

I have a `RewriteRule` that rewrites any request for a file containing a versioning part to the file without the version:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[0-9a-f]{32}(\.[0-9a-z]{2,6})$ $1$2 [L]
```

This means that whenever the file `styles.<version-id>.css` is requested, it is rewritten to `styles.css`. Now, how can I set the cache headers so that a file is cached for a longer period of time if the versioned version of the file is requested?

In other words, if the file `styles.css` is requeted, it should be cached for 24 hours, while the file `styles.<version-id>.css` should be cached for 365 days.

I've tried setting the cache using `FilesMatch` both before and after the rewrite using this snippet:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.[0-9a-f]{32}\.[0-9a-z]{2,6}">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

But it doesn't work. Maybe it doesn't match because the file name is rewritten. I don't know.

I've also tried using environment variables:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[0-9a-f]{32}(\.[0-9a-z]{2,6})$ $1$2 [L,E=AutoVersion]

Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public" env=AutoVersion
```

But I can't get this to work either.

Is there any way to set the caching policy of a rewritten request based on the original request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<FilesMatch>` matches physical files (not URLs), so this will never match a *URL* of the form `styles.<version-id>.css`, where the physical file is `styles.css`.

`<LocationMatch>` (in the server config) is the equivalent for URLs, but you are rewriting the URL and `<Location[Match]>` wrappers are applied late, so again, this will never match.

(Based on the format and behaviour of these directives, I assume these directives are in a directory/`.htaccess` context, as opposed to directly in the server config / virtual host?)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[0-9a-f]{32}(\.[0-9a-z]{2,6})$ $1$2 [L,E=AutoVersion]
>
> Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public" env=AutoVersion
> ```

But you can do this with the help of mod_rewrite to set an environment variable - much like you have done. This would have worked pretty much as-is if used directly in the server config. (Except that `REQUEST_FILENAME` would need to change to `LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME` to function as intended, otherwise the `RewriteCond` directive would *always* evaluate true.)

However, in a per-directory context, the rewriting process starts over after the initial rewrite and environment variables get prefixed with `REDIRECT_` (the original environment variable is not retained). So, you just need to change your `Header` directive to check this *renamed* environment variable instead. For example:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public" env=REDIRECT_AutoVersion
```